# "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'msgspec._core'",

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to include a python library in AWS lambda as a layer. The library is included but the interpreter is not identifying file msgspec._core. It gives the following error. I am using python version 3.9. I did try python version 3.8 as well but got the same error.

> Response {   **"errorMessage": "Unable to import module
> 'lambda_function': No module named 'msgspec._core'",**   "errorType":
> "Runtime.ImportModuleError",   "requestId":
> "ab9ed15b-2312-4204-985e-bc8cf1566c6b",   "stackTrace": [] }
>
> Function Logs START RequestId: ab9ed15b-2312-4204-985e-bc8cf1566c6b
> Version: $LATEST [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import
> module 'lambda_function': No module named 'msgspec._core' Traceback
> (most recent call last):END RequestId:
> ab9ed15b-2312-4204-985e-bc8cf1566c6b REPORT RequestId:
> ab9ed15b-2312-4204-985e-bc8cf1566c6b  Duration: 20.25 ms  Billed
> Duration: 21 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB  Init
> Duration: 347.62 ms
>
> Request ID ab9ed15b-2312-4204-985e-bc8cf1566c6b

I will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to deploy the code along with the required modules as a .zip file to aws lambda.
You can use VS Code's AWS extension to directly deploy your code and requirements onto aws lambda.

As you're using Python 3.9 and aws uses linux you should follow the below steps:
Download the msgspec.whl file for the above platform (py 3.9 and linux x86_64) from pypi. Here's the link :

[msgspec.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/92/c7b68460bd3d4fa9b5f2bf80c2c8477015a51c3d4d900946472b77027dbb/msgspec-0.13.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl)

Find other python versions here (x86_64.manylinux) -
https://pypi.org/project/msgspec/#files

Download the file in the directory where your lambda code is present(locally).

Then install wheel on your pc and unpack the file you just downloaded.

```
pip install wheel
wheel unpack <wheel_file_name>
```

Now zip the entire directory and deploy it to the lambda function.